# showing 2 custom attributes in 1 column in customers grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, search, customer-group, address

I am working on Magento system. In admin, customer has more than one address and I have street column in the grid which displays default billing street. But I want to search street name through all customer's addresses.

So user can enter street name to search users in the grid, And system should search through all addresses customer has.

Comment: So, you need to change the grid view of the Customer, so that the user can search through all the addresses available for a customer.

Comment: yes, so street column should be 'street1 street2 street3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this links, it contains the required help for the coding:

```
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rahul. I have used second solution (custom-renderer) and it is working.